# defining function term of a sine graph

Tags: functional-analysis

So I got a bit an easy question for you, but a bit a difficult for me.

We know, a sine-function is built this way:

$$f(x) = a\sin(bx-c)+d.$$

Our exercise is, to define the sine-function from the graph. I know how to find $a$, $b$, and $d$. But not $c$ (the shifting in $x$-axis). How can I calculate it?

And if the max-point of the function is e.g. on (0|1), how do I know if the graph is shifted or just mirrored on $x$-axis? E.g. these two look the same for me

$f(x) = -\sin(x-\pi)$

$f(x) = \sin(x)$

Comment: I tried to add a picture of a graph but I can't. stackexchange gives me an error :(

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yes, it's much better now. Thanks.

Comment: This kind of question doesn't have a unique answer. For example you're correct in observing that those two graphs (in the end of your post) look the same because they are indeed **the same** -- these two functions are identically equal to each other, due to properties of the sine function.

Comment: @zipirovich ah okay. so both would be correct... good to know :D - and how can I calculate c? I really have no idea :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A graph is shifted of $k>0$ units in the positive direction (usually the right direction) when considering $y=f(x-k)$ with respect to the graph of $y=f(x)$. If you consider $y=f(x+k)$ then the graph is shifted to the left of $k$ units

See the picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DJMNm.jpg)

(sorry but the image loader doesn't work)

Comment: (Ahh that's why I couldn't add a picture :p) Ahh okay, and now I need to calculate the value of k... you got me a hint for calculating it? The image is a great example. from image I'd say it's `1` but in real it's `pi/3` (and that is not equal to 1). How do I know it's `pi/3`?

Comment: Because for $x=\pi/3$ we have $\sin (x-\pi/3)=0$ not for $x=1$

Comment: I'm feeling dumb.. so easy.. :D thank you Raffaele

Answer (score 0):

Say we're given the graph of $a\sin(bx-c)+d$ and we want to find the function's variables. And assume that we know all points of the graph exactly.

One way of finding the variables is to define $m$ as the minimum of the graph with least $x$-value and $M$ as the maximum with least $x$-value such that $x_M>x_m$. Then $$\begin{aligned}|a|&=\frac{y_M-y_m}{2}\\
\\
|b|&=\frac{\pi}{x_M-x_m}\\
\\
c&\equiv b \cdot x_M-\frac{\pi}{2}\mod2\pi\\
\\d&=\frac{y_M+y_m}{2}\end{aligned}$$

so the *only* variable we can actually find out exactly is $d$. We don't know the sign of $a$ nor $b$ and $c$ can take infinitely many values.

Comment: NB: $c$ effectively takes two sets of values: those for $\hat{b}>0$ and those for $\hat{b}<0$ where $\hat{b}$ is the estimation of $b$.